# Java Hangman Oop static, non-static

Tags: java, oop

```
  i++){
            System.out.print("You have made the following guesses: " + guesses[i]);     
        }
        System.out.println("You have " + getMaxNumGuesses() + " remaining.");


    }

    private char getCh(){
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        char chosench = scanner1.nextLine().charAt(0);
        return chosench;
     }

    private boolean gameOver(){
        return blank.equals(word);
    }
}
```

When I try to run this code, it says "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method playGame() from the type Hangman.
I'm not sure why Java is producing this error. How am I making a static reference?
I have some ideas of fixing this problem (by creating the instance of an object Letter), but I'm not so sure if that's the right way to go from here.

Thanks for all your help!

Follow up question:

```
   // checks if the guessed character is right
        private boolean isGuessRight(char chr){
            Letter l = new Letter('a',false);
            for (int i = 0 ; i < word.length() ; i++){
                if (word.charAt(i) == chr && Letter.getRevealed() == false){
                    Letter.reveal();
                    return true;
                }
                else if (word.charAt(i) == chr && Letter.getRevealed()){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Why can I not call the method getRevealed() from the class Letter?
I'm not sure why it gives me the static, non-static error again. getRevealed is non static method and my isGuessRight is also a non-static method. I'm not sure where the clash is happening!

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args){ playGame();}` is your problem. You need `new Hangman().playGame()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because your `main` is static and you are trying to call non-static method `playGame()` from it.

This is how you should be calling your `playGame()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hangman h = new Hangman();
    h.playGame();
}
```

Comment: Sorry Boris, corrected it. Thanks for highlighting.

Comment: Hangman h = new Hangman();
    h.playGame();    Does that create a new instance of the class "Hangman" under the main method?

Comment: @SAValkyrie Yes! It is needed because otherwise you can only deal with static methods in main.

Comment: With my Hangman constructor, I have two parameters associated with it public Hangman (String, int) ; I'm not sure how to initialize that using the method that you have suggested. Any insights?

Comment: @SAValkyrie You should just do something like `Hangman h = new Hangman("myString", 0);`